# The test hangs for a decent amount of time and crashes with an error Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

When running tests, a Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout) error occurs.
The error occurs only in situations of switching to a new window.

At the same time, the problem is not even in the exception itself, but in the consequences. The fact is that when a problem occurs, the test does not fall, and a decent time (up to 10 minutes) waits before is crashed.

At the same time, there are no exceptions in the server console and browser console.

I use Capybara (selenium), chromediver 102.0.5005.61 and chrome .

```
client  = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
      client.read_timeout = 80
      options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
      options.add_preference('profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads', {
               '*': {'setting': 1}
                })
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, http_client: client, options: options)
```

It is code to switch to new window

```
window_last = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last
    log window_last
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(window_last)
```

There is a hook that should work, it seems to work, but for some reason it does not interrupt the test

```
After do |scenario|  
  if scenario.failed?
     filename = scenario.location.file.split('/').pop.split('.').shift 
     path = "#{ENV['ROOTDIR']}/06_Reports/error/#{filename}#{scenario.id}.png"
     p path
     page.save_screenshot path
  end
  page.driver.browser.close
  page.driver.quit()
end
```

[Video record](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HHcyhZHJfNckikT_CXKkI2AWbXrDqjQg/view?usp=sharing)

It seems to me that it started after updating chrome and chromedriver - but I'm not sure. It is not possible to repeat it manually, it is possible to run the autotest, and far from the first attempt.

Any idea what it is, where to dig? How to prevent such freezes? They greatly increase the run time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it started after updating chrome/chromedriver then it's likely a bug in chromedriver. Try rolling back to a previous version of chrome and seeing if the issue goes away. One thing to note is that by switching windows directly on the driver you are preventing Capybara from knowing about the window switch which can lead to issues. You should instead use the `Capybara::Session#switch_to_window` or `within_window` methods to do window switching.

Comment: Thomas, 
I'm having trouble finding an older version of Chrome to rollback to. Don't you know how to do it?